# How can I use $_GET url variable to redirect the user?

Tags: url, variables, redirect, get, forward

Thank you for your time. I am completely new to PHP and have very little experience so your patience and understanding is very much appreciated.

I am trying to create an exit page which I can display to my users for 5 seconds and then send them to a third party website.

I want to do this on the fly (for example exit.php?site=google.com)

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url="<?php
echo 'http://www.' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["site"]) . '/';
?>">
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the PHP code

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

most likely. What you can try doing is this:

```
$url = "refresh:5; url=http://www.".$_GET['site'];
header($url)
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to add the 5 second wait time.

Comment: Just added a way to do it. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I'd like to send you a small donation if you have a PayPal account?

Comment: I appreciate the offer but there's no need, just here to help someone out.