# PHP to send to url

Tags: php, url

Hello there i am running a daily deal website and i want to send my users to stores but currently my href is direct.

e.g - http://www.flipkart.com

and i want some php script so that i can make my url like this as i want to add affiliate script on "/go.php?url=(STORE URL)" -

e.g - http://www.mywebsite.com/go.php?url=http://www.flipkart.com

Please help me..

Comment: Please tell us about your motivation to redirect users to foreign URLs instead of direct linking. Do you want to log the redirects!?

Comment: A mechanism, like the one you describe above ( ie: `go.php?url=` ) is prone to abuse as spammers can target that url with any url of their choosing - thus making it appear that traffic is originating from your site. Be careful with this approach, better would be to use an id from the db which is validated before sending the user

Comment: If you're going to use the php redirect make sure you call it before any output is sent

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following techniques.

**1. HTML Redirect.**

Use code like this.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?php echo $_GET['url'] ?>" />
```

More details [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)

**2. PHP redirect**

```
<?php header("Location: $_GET['url']"); ?>
```

Make sure there should not be any space before this tag. this should be the first line

**3. JavaScript Redirect**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            function Redirect() {
               window.location="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>";
            }
            setTimeout('Redirect()', 10);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note: Even you can use combining all this three for must work (Fallback case if any).

Comment: But as i am new to coding i am not getting it.. pls

Comment: http://wwww.onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url=http://www.flipkart.com/trendzo-7-w-led-trn-bulb/p/itmefdbbhgzm9c2g  Its Showing error

Comment: CORR: http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url=http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00DRB3VFU   Typo in the URL.

Comment: This approach is also prone to abuse by spammers

Comment: Yes. You are right @RamRaider. They will push their URL. So that it will be redirect to theier pages.

Comment: i added my cuelinks affiliate script to go.php but its not working

Comment: Abuse: Alternatively you could provide an ID/key as the GET parameter, and keep the URLs to redirect to hidden in the script. Of course, the list of URLs would need administration when someting changes.

Comment: Your URL is working for me. May be in your browser JavaScript is off or you are checking something else. Try HTML meta tag in head also.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            function Redirect() {
               window.location="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>";
            }
            setTimeout('Redirect()', 10);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var pubID = '9318CL8605';
(function(d, t) {
var s = document.createElement('script');s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;s.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://cdn0.cuelinks.com/js/' : 'http://cdn0.cuelinks.com/js/')  + 'cuelinksv1.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
}());
</script>

Answer (score 0):

perform a redirection at go.php

```
 <?php
    header("Location: $_GET['url']");
    ?>
```

If you want to give a warning to user that redirecting to this site by giving a refresh time and then redirecting [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601748/how-can-i-use-get-url-variable-to-redirect-the-user).

Comment: http://wwww.onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url=http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00DRB3VFUIt showing Error

Comment: CORR: http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url=http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00DRB3VFU   You had a typo.